# Python selenium not giving the desired output on digital ocean droplet

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

when I hit the url "expert.chegg.com/expertqna" I should get the following output as the page source.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
      <title>Sign In</title>
      <link rel='icon' href='https://media.cheggcdn.com/coop/dee/dee54b6f-3c3d-46c8-8176-c249a02f925d/1621571294284_chegg.ico' />
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=0" />
    </head>
    <body>
    
      <!--[if IE 8]>
      <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ie8/0.2.5/ie8.js"></script>
      <![endif]-->
    
      <!--[if lte IE 9]>
      <script src="https://cdn.auth0.com/js/base64.js"></script>
      <script src="https://cdn.auth0.com/js/es5-shim.min.js"></script>
      <![endif]-->
    
      <script src="https://cdn.auth0.com/js/lock/11.27/lock.min.js"></script>
      <script>
        // Decode utf8 characters properly
        var config = JSON.parse(decodeURIComponent(escape(window.atob('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'))));
        config.extraParams = config.extraParams || {};
        var connection = config.connection;
        var prompt = config.prompt;
        var languageDictionary;
        var language;
    
        if (config.dict && config.dict.signin && config.dict.signin.title) {
          languageDictionary = { title: config.dict.signin.title };
        } else if (typeof config.dict === 'string') {
          language = config.dict;
        }
        var loginHint = config.extraParams.login_hint;
        var colors = config.colors || {};
    
        // Available Lock configuration options: https://auth0.com/docs/libraries/lock/v11/configuration
        
        var lock = new Auth0Lock(config.clientID, config.auth0Domain, {
          auth: {
            redirectUrl: config.callbackURL,
            responseType: (config.internalOptions || {}).response_type ||
              (config.callbackOnLocationHash ? 'token' : 'code'),
            params: config.internalOptions
          },
          configurationBaseUrl: config.clientConfigurationBaseUrl,
          overrides: {
            __tenant: config.auth0Tenant,
            __token_issuer: config.authorizationServer.issuer
          },
          assetsUrl:  config.assetsUrl,
          allowedConnections: connection ? [connection] : null,
          rememberLastLogin: !prompt,
          language: language,
          languageDictionary: {
            ...languageDictionary,
            error: {
                login: {
                "lock.invalid_email_password": "The email or password you entered is incorrect."
              }
            },
                forgotPasswordAction: "Forgot password?",
            blankPasswordErrorHint: "Password field cannot be empty",
                blankEmailErrorHint: "Email field cannot be empty",
            invalidEmailErrorHint: "Please enter a valid email",
            emailInputPlaceholder: "Email",
            passwordInputPlaceholder: "Password",
            loginSubmitLabel: 'Sign in',
            // forgotPasswordInstructions: "Please enter your registered email address to receive instructions on how to reset your password.",
            forgotPasswordInstructions: "",
            success: {
                forgotPassword: `We’ve sent you an email to reset your password.`,
            }
          },
          theme: {
            logo:            config.icon,
            primaryColor:    colors.primary ? colors.primary : 'green',
            authButtons: {
              "okta-oauth2": {
                displayName: "Okta",
                primaryColor: "#027dc12a",
                foregroundColor: "#027dc1",
                icon: "https://symbols-electrical.getvecta.com/stencil_90/13_okta-icon.9a16ac9161.png"
              }
            }
          },
          prefill: loginHint ? { email: loginHint, username: loginHint } : null,
          allowShowPassword: true,
          closable: false,
          defaultADUsernameFromEmailPrefix: false
        });
        
        var pageBackgroundUrl = 'https://media.cheggcdn.com/coop/7cc/7cca2499-3d59-46ee-94a3-dcc5412ab4a3/1611143731736_BackgroundImage.jpg';
            var inputWidth = 288;
        
        if(colors.page_background) {
          // existing classes
          var css = `
                    .auth0-lock-header-bg-solid {
                        background-color: rgb(113, 113, 113) !important;
                    }
                    .auth0-loading-container {
                        opacity: 0 !important;
                    }
                    .auth0-lock.auth0-lock.auth0-lock-opened {
                        background-color: #000;
                    }
                    .auth0-lock.auth0-lock.auth0-lock-opened .auth0-lock-overlay {
                        opacity: 0.3;
                    }
                    .auth0-lock.auth0-lock .auth0-lock-widget {
                        width: 400px;
                    }
                    .auth0-lock.auth0-lock .auth0-lock-content-wrapper {
                        height: 500px;
                    }
                    .auth0-lock.auth0-lock .auth0-lock-overlay {
                        background: url("${pageBackgroundUrl}");
                        background-size: cover;
                    }
                    .auth0-lock.auth0-lock .auth0-lock-header {
                        padding: 16px;
                    }
                    .auth0-lock.auth0-lock .auth0-lock-header-logo {
                        height: 40px;
                    }
                    .auth0-lock-name {
                        display: none;
                    }
                    .auth0-lock.auth0-lock .auth0-lock-form {
                        display: flex;
                        justify-content: center;
                        margin-top: 0;
                    }
                    .auth0-lock.auth0-lock .auth0-lock-form p {
                        width: ${inputWidth}px !important;
                    }
                    .auth0-lock.auth0-lock .auth0-lock-content-body-wrapper {}
                    .auth0-lock-input-block {
                        margin-bottom: 32px !important;
                        width: ${inputWidth}px !important;
                    }
                    .auth0-lock.auth0-lock .auth0-lock-input-wrap {
                        border-radius: 0;
                        background-color: #fff;
                        border: solid 2px #e7e7e7;
                    }
                    .auth0-lock.auth0-lock .auth0-lock-input-wrap .auth0-lock-input {
                        font-size: 16px !important;
                    }
                    .auth0-lock.auth0-lock .auth0-lock-input-wrap.auth0-lock-input-wrap-with-icon {
                        padding-left: 0;
                    }
                    .auth0-lock.auth0-lock .auth0-lock-input-wrap.auth0-lock-input-wrap-with-icon > span {
                        display: none;
                    }
                    .auth0-lock.auth0-lock .auth0-lock-input-wrap.auth0-lock-focused {
                        border: solid 2px #00799E;
                    }
                    .auth0-lock.auth0-lock .auth0-lock-form .auth0-lock-alternative {
                        text-align: left
                    }
                    .auth0-lock-alternative-link {
                        color: #00799E !important;
                        font-size: 14px;
                        font-weight: 700;
                    }
                    /*.auth0-lock-submit[aria-label="Log In"] .auth0-label-submit {
                        visibility: hidden;
                    }
                    .auth0-lock-submit[aria-label="Log In"] .auth0-label-submit:after {
                        visibility: visible;
                        content: 'Sign in';
                        margin-left: -72px;
                    }*/
                    .auth0-label-submit {
                        text-transform: none;
                        font-weight: 700;
                        font-size: 20px;
                        height: unset !important;
                        line-height: unset !important;
                    }
                    .auth0-label-submit span {
                        display: none !important;
                    }
                    .auth0-lock.auth0-lock .auth0-global-message {
                        margin: 0 32px;
                        padding: 8px 16px;
                        color: #000;
                        font-size: 16px;
                        font-weight: 500;
                        line-height: 20px;
                        text-transform: none;
                        text-align: left;
                        position: relative;
                    }
                    .auth0-lock-error-msg {
                        position: absolute;
                    }
                    .auth0-lock.auth0-lock .auth0-global-message.auth0-global-message-success {
                        border: 1px solid #229d9e;
                        background-color: #eaf8f8;
                        z-index: 2;
                    }
                    .auth0-lock.auth0-lock .auth0-global-message.auth0-global-message-error {
                        border: 1px solid #fa5f4a;
                        background-color: #fff3f2;
                        z-index: 2;
                    }
                `;
          
          // custom classes
          css = css + `
                    .auth0-custom-headmessage {
                        text-align: center;
              font-size: 16px;
                        font-weight: normal;
                        padding: 8px 16px;
                        margin-top: 16px;
                    }
                    .auth0-custom-headmessage p {
                        font-size: 18px;
                        margin-bottom: 0 !important;
                        line-height: 8px;
                    }
                    .auth0-custom-hdmsghead {
              font-size: 20px;
                        font-weight: 600;
                    }
                    .auth0-lock-namenew {
                        text-align: center;
                        z-index: 2;
              font-size: 20px;
                        font-weight: 600;
                        color: #000;
                    }
                    .auth0-custom-tnc {
                        text-align: center;
                        padding: 0 16px;
                        margin-top: -16px;
                        font-size: 16px;
                    }
                    .auth0-custom-tnc > a {
                        color: #00799E !important;
                        text-decoration: none;
                        cursor: pointer;
                        font-weight: 600;
                    }
                `;
          
          var style = document.createElement('style');
    
          style.appendChild(document.createTextNode(css));
    
          document.body.appendChild(style);
        }
    
        lock.show();
        
        const headerElem = document.getElementsByClassName('auth0-lock-header')[0];
        if (headerElem) {
            headerElem.insertAdjacentHTML('afterend', `
                    <div class='auth0-custom-headmessage'>
                            <p class='auth0-custom-hdmsghead' id='custom-msg-head'> Sign in </p>
                            <p id='custom-msg-para'> with your email and password </p>
                </div>
                `);
          headerElem.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', `
                    <div class='auth0-lock-namenew' id = 'headname'>
                            The Expert Hub
                </div>
                `);
        }
        
        lock.on('signin ready', () => {
          const headEl = document.getElementById('custom-msg-head');
          if (headEl) {
            headEl.innerText = 'Sign in'
          }
          
          const paraEl = document.getElementById('custom-msg-para');
          if (paraEl) {
            paraEl.innerText = 'with your email and password'
          }
        });
        
        
        lock.on('forgot_password ready', () => {
          const headEl = document.getElementById('custom-msg-head');
          if (headEl) {
            headEl.innerText = 'Forgot Password'
          }
          
          const paraEl = document.getElementById('custom-msg-para');
          if (paraEl) {
            paraEl.style.lineHeight = '1.2';
            paraEl.style.fontSize = '16px';
            paraEl.innerText = 'Enter your registered email ID. We will send you an email to reset your password'
          }
    
          const formElem = document.getElementsByClassName('auth0-lock-form')[0];
          if (formElem) {
            formElem.insertAdjacentHTML('afterend', `
                        <div class='auth0-custom-tnc'>
                            By resetting your password, you agree to the
                            <br>
                            <a href="https://www.chegg.com/termsofuse" target="_blank">Terms of Use</a> and 
                            <a href="https://www.chegg.com/privacypolicy" target="_blank">Privacy Policy</a>
                        </div>
                    `);
          }
        });
    
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

but I am getting the below page source:

```
<html lang="en"><head><meta charset="utf-8"><link rel="shortcut icon" href="/chegg.ico"><meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1"><meta name="theme-color" content="#000000"><link rel="manifest" href="/manifest.json"><title>Chegg</title><script type="text/javascript" src="https://bam.nr-data.net/1/1fabaefecb?a=500886526&amp;sa=1&amp;v=1167.2a4546b&amp;t=Unnamed%20Transaction&amp;rst=38146&amp;ref=https://expert.chegg.com/expertqna&amp;be=4565&amp;fe=35360&amp;dc=17729&amp;af=err,xhr,stn,ins,spa&amp;perf=%7B%22timing%22:%7B%22of%22:1624790790145,%22n%22:0,%22f%22:-2,%22dn%22:0,%22dne%22:273,%22c%22:273,%22s%22:381,%22ce%22:1900,%22rq%22:1900,%22rp%22:3958,%22rpe%22:3958,%22dl%22:3969,%22di%22:17708,%22ds%22:17728,%22de%22:17728,%22dc%22:35359,%22l%22:35359,%22le%22:35361%7D,%22navigation%22:%7B%7D%7D&amp;fcp=17570&amp;ja=%7B%22userUUID%22:%22%22%7D&amp;jsonp=NREUM.setToken"></script><script src="https://js-agent.newrelic.com/nr-spa-1167.min.js"></script><script src="/nr-browser.js" type="text/javascript"></script><link href="/static/css/2.1d5ea050.chunk.css" rel="stylesheet"><style data-styled="" data-styled-version="4.4.0"></style></head><body><noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript><div id="root"><header class="sc-cooIXK iSIUkB"><div class="sc-fcdeBU IqMmO"><svg aria-label="Menu" role="img" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 60 60" class="sc-hGoxap gjihCl sc-RcBXQ ijill" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet"><g transform="translate(18, 17)"><path d="M24,0.5H0" class="sc-TFwJa cskvsh"></path><path d="M24,12.5H0" class="sc-TFwJa cskvsh"></path><path d="M24,24.5H0" class="sc-TFwJa cskvsh"></path></g></svg><a href="/home" aria-label="Chegg home" class="sc-gmeYpB jbWjZR"><svg aria-label="Chegg" role="img" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 211 64" id="logo-story-Chegg" class="sc-hGoxap eHpivK sc-itybZL eouJLu" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet"><path d="M204.6,13.6c-3.1,0-5.7,2.4-5.7,5.4s2.4,5.7,5.7,5.7c3.1,0,5.7-2.4,5.7-5.4C210.3,16,207.9,13.6,204.6,13.6L204.6,13.6L204.6,13.6z M204.6,23.6c-2.4,0-4.3-1.9-4.3-4.5c0-2.4,1.9-4.5,4.3-4.3c2.4,0,4.3,2.1,4.3,4.5c0,1.1-0.4,2.2-1.2,3C206.8,23.1,205.7,23.6,204.6,23.6L204.6,23.6L204.6,23.6z M205.8,19.3L205.8,19.3c0.7-0.2,1.2-0.7,1.2-1.4c0-0.4-0.2-0.9-0.5-1.2c-0.6-0.3-1.2-0.5-1.9-0.5c-0.9,0-1.7,0-2.1,0.2v5.4h1.2v-2.1h0.7c0.7,0,0.9,0.2,1.2,0.9c0.2,0.7,0.2,1.2,0.5,1.4h1.4c0-0.2-0.2-0.5-0.5-1.4C206.7,20,206.5,19.5,205.8,19.3L205.8,19.3L205.8,19.3L205.8,19.3z M204.4,18.8h-0.7v-1.7h0.7c0.7,0,1.2,0.2,1.2,0.9C205.8,18.6,205.1,18.8,204.4,18.8L204.4,18.8z M34.4,31.1c-2.8,0.5-4,3.8-5.9,5.4c-2.1,2.1-6.1,2.1-8.7,0.7c-5-2.8-5-8.3-5-13.5c0-4.5,1.9-9.2,5.9-11.1c5.4-2.1,8.7,2.8,12.3,5.9c3.3,1.2,7.8,1.4,10.6-0.9c0.9-1.9,0.2-4.5-0.7-6.1c-1.4-3.3-5-6.9-8-8c-6.6-3.3-16.3-3.3-23.2,0C6.5,6.1,2.5,11.5,1.1,17c-2.4,9.5-0.9,20.1,6.4,27c6.9,6.1,18.4,6.6,26.7,3.3c5.2-2.6,9.9-8,10.2-13.9C43.1,29.5,37.7,31.1,34.4,31.1L34.4,31.1L34.4,31.1z M79.1,16.7C74.8,12,68,12.9,62.8,14.8c-5-1.4-2.1-8-4.3-11.6c-2.8-2.4-8.7-2.6-11.1,0.7c-1.2,10.6-0.2,22.2-0.7,33.1c0.7,3.3-0.7,7.6,2.1,9.9c2.8,1.2,6.6,0.9,9.5-0.5c1.9-5.2,0.7-11.8,1.7-17.5l2.1-3.8c1.2-0.7,2.8-1.4,4.3-0.7c5,2.6,3.1,9,3.3,13.9c0,3.1-0.5,6.6,2.1,8.7c2.4,0.7,5,0.7,7.6,0.2c1.7-0.5,2.8-2.4,3.1-3.8C81.9,34.2,84.5,23.8,79.1,16.7L79.1,16.7L79.1,16.7z M91.6,16.7C85.9,21,84,27.8,85,34.9c1.2,5.7,5.4,11.1,10.9,12.5c7.8,1.9,17.7,1.7,22.7-5.7c0.7-1.4,0.5-3.3-1.2-4c-4.3-2.1-8.3,0.7-11.8,2.1c-2.4,0.7-5,0.2-6.1-1.9c-0.7-1.4,0-3.3,1.4-3.8c6.9-1.9,13.9,3.5,19.9-1.4c2.1-4.5-0.2-9-2.4-12.5C112.2,12,99.2,11,91.6,16.7L91.6,16.7L91.6,16.7L91.6,16.7z M106.7,25.7c-1.4,1.2-4,1.9-5.9,0.5c-1.4-0.5-1.4-2.1-0.9-3.1c1.4-1.9,5.2-1.9,6.6-0.2C106.7,23.8,107.4,24.8,106.7,25.7L106.7,25.7L106.7,25.7L106.7,25.7zM158,15.3c-3.3-2.1-7.6-0.9-10.9,0c-5.4-1.9-13.7-3.8-18.4,1.2c-4,3.8-5.2,9-5,14.9c0,3.5,1.2,7.1,3.5,9.7c1.2,1.4,2.8,2.8,4.7,4c3.5,2.6,8.3,0.7,12.3,0.2c1.4,0.2,2.6,1.9,1.9,3.5c-0.9,2.1-3.1,3.1-5.2,2.6c-3.5-2.6-9-2.6-13-0.7c-0.2,1.2-0.7,2.4,0,3.5c0.5,0.5,0.9,0.7,1.2,1.2c6.4,5,16.1,4.3,23.2,2.1c3.3-1.7,5.9-5.2,6.4-8.7c0.9-9.9,0.9-20.6,0.5-31L158,15.3L158,15.3L158,15.3zM143.9,35.6c-1.7,0.9-3.3,0.5-4.7-0.2c-1.4-1.7-2.6-3.3-2.4-5.9c-0.2-2.1,0.7-3.8,2.1-5.2c1.7-1.4,4.5-1.4,6.1,0.2c1.4,1.4,1.9,3.3,2.1,5.4C146.7,32.1,145.7,34.4,143.9,35.6L143.9,35.6L143.9,35.6L143.9,35.6L143.9,35.6z M196.1,15.3c-3.3-2.1-7.6-0.9-10.9,0c-5.4-1.9-13.7-3.8-18.4,1.2c-4,3.8-5.2,9-5,14.9c0,3.5,1.2,7.1,3.5,9.7c1.2,1.4,2.8,2.8,4.7,4c3.5,2.6,8.3,0.7,12.3,0.2c1.4,0.2,2.6,1.9,1.9,3.5c-0.9,2.1-3.1,3.1-5.2,2.6c-3.5-2.6-9-2.6-13-0.7c-0.2,1.2-0.7,2.4,0,3.5c0.5,0.5,0.9,0.7,1.2,1.2c6.4,5,16.1,4.3,23.2,2.1c3.3-1.7,5.9-5.2,6.4-8.7c0.9-9.9,0.9-20.6,0.5-31L196.1,15.3L196.1,15.3L196.1,15.3z M181.9,35.6c-1.7,0.9-3.3,0.5-4.7-0.2c-1.4-1.7-2.6-3.3-2.4-5.9c-0.2-2.1,0.7-3.8,2.1-5.2c1.7-1.4,4.5-1.4,6.1,0.2c1.4,1.4,1.9,3.3,2.1,5.4C184.8,32.1,183.8,34.4,181.9,35.6L181.9,35.6L181.9,35.6L181.9,35.6L181.9,35.6z"></path></svg></a><nav class="sc-jXQZqI gqltHm"><a class="sc-iGPElx bzILNB" data-test-id="home-nav-link" href="/home">Home</a><a aria-current="page" class="sc-iGPElx bzILNB active" data-test-id="expert-qna-nav-link" href="/expertqna">Expert Q&amp;A</a><a class="sc-iGPElx bzILNB" data-test-id="my-answers-nav-link" href="/myanswers">My answers</a></nav><div data-test-id="my-account" class="sc-kasBVs gMUZJc"><div class="sc-hgHYgh gIvmK"><div class="sc-fOICqy dcgsVs"><img src="data:image/png;base64,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" alt="profile-image" class="sc-hzDEsm OtctG"></div><svg aria-hidden="true" role="presentation" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 60 60" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet" class="sc-hGoxap ixmAZa"><g transform="translate(18, 18)"><polyline points="23.3,12 12,23.3 0.7,12 0.7,12" class="sc-TFwJa cfsMky"></polyline></g></svg></div></div></div></header><main class="sc-chbbiW jYDNWv"><div class="sc-jtRlXQ kbOHtO"><div type="1" aria-live="polite" role="status" class="sc-hrWEMg gTFAJZ"><div class="sc-eTuwsz jJKLAU"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="20" height="20" viewBox="0 0 40 40"><path fill="#fa5f4a" fill-rule="evenodd" d="M20 40C8.954 40 0 31.046 0 20S8.954 0 20 0s20 8.954 20 20-8.954 20-20 20zm-3-11c0 1.653 1.343 3 3 3 1.653 0 3-1.343 3-3 0-1.653-1.343-3-3-3-1.653 0-3 1.343-3 3zm0-17v9a3 3 0 0 0 6 0v-9a3 3 0 0 0-6 0z"></path></svg></div><div class="sc-gwVKww ONznD"><div class="sc-iQNlJl iceRYh">Something went wrong. Please refresh the page for a new question</div></div></div></div></main></div><script>!function(l){function e(e){for(var r,t,n=e[0],o=e[1],u=e[2],f=0,i=[];f<n.length;f++)t=n[f],p[t]&&i.push(p[t][0]),p[t]=0;for(r in o)Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(o,r)&&(l[r]=o[r]);for(s&&s(e);i.length;)i.shift()();return c.push.apply(c,u||[]),a()}function a(){for(var e,r=0;r<c.length;r++){for(var t=c[r],n=!0,o=1;o<t.length;o++){var u=t[o];0!==p[u]&&(n=!1)}n&&(c.splice(r--,1),e=f(f.s=t[0]))}return e}var t={},p={1:0},c=[];function f(e){if(t[e])return t[e].exports;var r=t[e]={i:e,l:!1,exports:{}};return l[e].call(r.exports,r,r.exports,f),r.l=!0,r.exports}f.m=l,f.c=t,f.d=function(e,r,t){f.o(e,r)||Object.defineProperty(e,r,{enumerable:!0,get:t})},f.r=function(e){"undefined"!=typeof Symbol&&Symbol.toStringTag&&Object.defineProperty(e,Symbol.toStringTag,{value:"Module"}),Object.defineProperty(e,"__esModule",{value:!0})},f.t=function(r,e){if(1&e&&(r=f(r)),8&e)return r;if(4&e&&"object"==typeof r&&r&&r.__esModule)return r;var t=Object.create(null);if(f.r(t),Object.defineProperty(t,"default",{enumerable:!0,value:r}),2&e&&"string"!=typeof r)for(var n in r)f.d(t,n,function(e){return r[e]}.bind(null,n));return t},f.n=function(e){var r=e&&e.__esModule?function(){return e.default}:function(){return e};return f.d(r,"a",r),r},f.o=function(e,r){return Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(e,r)},f.p="/";var r=window.webpackJsonp=window.webpackJsonp||[],n=r.push.bind(r);r.push=e,r=r.slice();for(var o=0;o<r.length;o++)e(r[o]);var s=n;a()}([])</script><script src="/static/js/2.4abd1879.chunk.js"></script><script src="/static/js/main.dd0efd0d.chunk.js"></script></body></html>
```

My python selenium code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys


def index(request):
    if(request.method == "POST"):
        body_unicode = request.body.decode('utf-8')
        body = json.loads(body_unicode)

        username = body['username']
        password = body['password']
        fireFoxOptions = webdriver.FirefoxOptions()
        fireFoxOptions.headless = True
        #firefoxProfile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
        #firefoxProfile.set_preference("xpinstall.signatures.required", False)
        #firefoxProfile.update_preferences()
        driver = webdriver.Firefox(options=fireFoxOptions)
        # driver = webdriver.Firefox()
        driver.get("https://expert.chegg.com/expertqna")
        # assert "Python" in driver.title
        # elem = driver.find_element_by_name("q")
        # elem.clear()
        # elem.send_keys("pycon")
        # a = elem.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
        time.sleep(40)
        print(driver.page_source)
```

Note: 1. The code works in the local machine with firefox as well as chrome driver but doesn't work with either on digitalocean droplet.
2. I get the page that I hit not the page to which the site redirects after hitting the original link.

Answer (score 0):

> CheggYou need to enable JavaScript to run this app.HomeExpert Q&AMy
> answersSomething went wrong

The error is telling you to enable JavaScript, you can enable javascript via chrome options.

```
options.add_argument("javascript.enabled", True)
```

If that doesn't work then you can also try using the JavaScript flag

```
options.add_argument("--enable-javascript")
```

Comment: Still it doesn't work. and the surprising part is, it works on the local machine but doesn't work on digitalocean droplet. Can you suggest something? I am stuck on this from 5 AM in the morning.

Comment: I read somewhere that the new versions of firefox have some problem, then I copied the same binary as my local machine on the server still it doesn't work.

Comment: Do you have to use Firefox, it seems to work on with the [ChromeDriver](https://chromedriver.chromium.org/) on my PC. [Chrome 9.1](https://www.google.com/intl/en_uk/chrome/)

Comment: Still doesn't work and btw works in my local machine :-(

Answer (score 0):

After one week I found the solution.
Note: I am not underpromoting or promoting anything just sharing my own experience.

1. First of all I tried everything on digital ocean to run the headless browser. And it worked perfectly fine. But the particular website was not working on the digitalocean droplet for some reason(which I still don't know). After using vps(and actually seeing what is happening I noticed that the url that I am hitting is not loading for some reason. I checked the console, there were some errors(not able fetch 403 forbidden) which didn't help me draw any conclusion.
2. Then I tried Amazon aws server and it worked.

This may be very specific case that I faced. But if anyone faces this issue you may try this.